# Using an equation as part of an input for a VBA function?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently writing VBA code for a lab for one of my engineering classes. The goal is to use a single function to approximate (Trapezoidal Rule) the integral of a given equation. The equation will need to change at some point. I'm new to programming so I'm planning on seeing some sort of simple logic error. Here's what I currently have:

```
Function Trapezoidal(ByVal sFx As String, ByVal A As Double, _
 ByVal B As Double, ByVal N As Integer) As Double
' Calculates the area under the curve using the Trapezoidal rule.
'
' Parameters:
'
' sFx - String expression that has the function to be
' integrated. The variable X as to appear as $X.
' An example is: $X*LOG(X$) which is an expression for function
' f(x)=x*ln(x)
' A, B - Lower and Upper limit for the integral.
' N - The number of integration intervals.
'
 Dim Sum As Double, DeltaX As Double, X As Double
 Dim I As Integer

Sum = 0
 DeltaX = (B - A) / N
 X = A
 For I = 1 To N
 Sum = Sum + (Fx(sFx, X) + Fx(sFx, X + DeltaX)) / 2
 X = X + DeltaX
 Next I
 Sum = DeltaX * Sum
 Trapezoidal = Sum
End Function
```

I've sort of Frankensteined a few pieces of code together in my research.Something clearly isn

Comment: Probably the closest you can get is to use `Application.Evaluate()` and express your function as an Excel worksheet formula, substituting the value of X for the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print Trapezoidal("$X*LN($X)", 1, 20, 5)
End Sub


Function Trapezoidal(ByVal sFx As String, ByVal A As Double, _
                    ByVal B As Double, ByVal N As Integer) As Double
    ' Calculates the area under the curve using the Trapezoidal rule.
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '
    ' sFx - String expression that has the function to be
    ' integrated. The variable X as to appear as $X.
    ' An example is: $X*LOG(X$) which is an expression for function
    ' f(x)=x*ln(x)
    ' A, B - Lower and Upper limit for the integral.
    ' N - The number of integration intervals.
    '
    Dim Sum As Double, DeltaX As Double, X As Double
    Dim I As Integer, f As String

    Sum = 0
    DeltaX = (B - A) / N
    X = A
    For I = 1 To N
        'Sum = Sum + (Fx(sFx, X) + Fx(sFx, X + DeltaX)) / 2
        f = "(" & Replace(sFx, "$X", X) & " + " & Replace(sFx, "$X", X + DeltaX) & ")/2"
        Debug.Print f
        Sum = Sum + Application.Evaluate(f)
        X = X + DeltaX
    Next I
    Sum = DeltaX * Sum
    Trapezoidal = Sum
End Function
```

Debug output:

```
(1*LN(1) + 4.8*LN(4.8))/2
(4.8*LN(4.8) + 8.6*LN(8.6))/2
(8.6*LN(8.6) + 12.4*LN(12.4))/2
(12.4*LN(12.4) + 16.2*LN(16.2))/2
(16.2*LN(16.2) + 20*LN(20))/2
 502.848119401941
```